# jQuery firing functions when in mobile or desktop viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem I am having with my script is that it works fine onload but for example if you start off in mobile view (less than 500px) and click on the button it hide/shows the div correctly and stops the link from being clickable. But if you resize the screen to desktop the mobile function is still running and shows the div on click and stops the link from being clickable.

The same thing happens vice versa if you start in desktop view and go to mobile the desktop function still fires in mobile view

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong please?

https://jsfiddle.net/x2w3vp5n/1/

```
var fluid = function() {
  if ($(window).width() >= 500) {
    desktop();
  } else {
    mobile();
  }
};

// Fire on DOM ready
fluid();

// Fire upon resize
$(window).resize(fluid);

function desktop() {
  $('.container').on({
    mouseenter: function(e) {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    },
    mouseleave: function(e) {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
  });
}

function mobile() {
  $('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this).closest('.container');
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    $this.toggleClass('active');

    return false;
  });
}
```

Comment: seems to be working fine..  open console and test by resizing output window : https://jsfiddle.net/x2w3vp5n/3/

Comment: For example I want the link to be clickable on desktop but not on mobile. If you start off in mobile size the link isnt clickable (great)..expand the screen to desktop and mobile() function is still firing and stops the link from being clickable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "de-register" the handlers that are set up when the page first loads.

Any function you attach with `$().on` will continue to fire until you un-attach it using some thing like `$().off()`.

Because your `mobile` and `desktop` functions bind to different parts of the DOM you can just remove the opposite function's event binding at the top of each function:

```
var fluid = function() {
  if ($(window).width() >= 500) {
    desktop();
  } else {
    mobile();
  }
};

// Fire on DOM ready
fluid();

// Fire upon resize
$(window).resize(fluid);

function desktop() {
  //turn off mobile function attached to .btn
  $('.btn').off();
  $('.container').on({
    mouseenter: function(e) {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    },
    mouseleave: function(e) {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
  });
}

function mobile() {
  //turn off desktop function attached to .container
  $('.container').off();
  $('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this).closest('.container');
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

   $this.toggleClass('active');

    return false;
  });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ebbyntq5/

Comment: No problem, hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$(window).width()` jQuery will do a bunch of work to compute the actually available "window" (read browser window) size at that time.
If you want the 'actual screen size', you can use the JavaScript object `screen`, specifically `screen.width` and/or `screen.availWidth`.

Your code could then look like this:

```
var fluid = function() {
  if (screen.width >= 500) {
    desktop();
  } else {
    mobile();
  }
};
```

It's important to note that `screen` is not always perfect. I remember having issues on iPhones/iPads where the width and the height were flipped due to the orientation of the device.

Also in your code you only register eventlisteners (using `on()`), but you never remove them when they are not needed anymore (using `off()`).
This means the 'old' mobile events will still fire if you resize to desktop.

I updated your fiddle to remove the events: https://jsfiddle.net/x2w3vp5n/4/

Answer (score 0):

When you resize the window the listeners are already set, you have to remove the listeners before set the new ones in the fluid function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `$('.btn').on('click',...)` stop to work when desktop, you should explicitely switch off with `$('.btn').off('click')`, so:

```
function desktop() {
  $('.btn').on('click');
  $('.container').on({
     ...code...
  });
}

function mobile() {
  $('.container').off('mouseenter').off('mouseleave');
  $('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
     ...code...
  });
}
```